# There seams to be a overflow in my list but i cannot find it

Tags: c, memory

```
typedef struct PredNode {
   int         v;
   struct PredNode *next;
} PredNode;

typedef struct ShortestPaths {
   int noNodes;
   int src;
   int *dist;
   PredNode **pred;
} ShortestPaths;


ShortestPaths dijkstra(Graph g, Vertex v) {
    ShortestPaths throwAway;
    throwAway.src = v;
    throwAway.noNodes = g->nV;
    int i;
    int dist[g->nV];
    int visited[g->nV];

    PredNode **pred = malloc(g->nV*sizeof(PredNode *));
    Node **fake = malloc(g->nV*sizeof(Node *));
    for(i=0;i<g->nV;i++){
    pred[i] = NULL;
    fake[i] = NULL;
    dist[i] = 1000;
    visited[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<g->nV;i++){
        printf("%d:%d \n",i,dist[i]);
        if(dist[i]== 1000){
            dist[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    throwAway.dist = dist;
    throwAway.pred = pred;
    return throwAway;
}
```

and the printf out put is just fine whick is all zeros;
but when i printf it in check function:

```
void displayShortestPathsStruct(ShortestPaths sps){
    int i = 0;
    printf("Node %d\n",sps.src);
    printf("  Distance\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sps.noNodes; i++) {
        if(i == sps.src)
        printf("    %d : X\n",i);
        else
            printf("    %d : %d\n",i,sps.dist[i]);
    }
    printf("  Preds\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sps.noNodes; i++) {
        printf("    %d : ",i);
        PredNode* curr = sps.pred[i];
            while(curr!=NULL) {
            printf("[%d]->",curr->v);
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./testDijkstra [file]\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  Graph g = readGraph(argv[1]);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<numVerticies(g); i++) {
    ShortestPaths paths = dijkstra(g,i);
    displayShortestPathsStruct(paths);
    freeShortestPaths(paths);
  }
}
```

the output is :

```
0 : X
1 : 32767
2 : 0
3 : 0
4 : 45809225
5 : 1
6 : 314310766
7 : -1806535317
8 : 1560619552
9 : 32767
10 : -1912724920
11 : 32767
```

0 (0)
0 (0)
0:0
1:1000
2:1000
3:1000
4:1000
5:1000
6:1000
7:1000
8:1000
9:1000
10:1000
11:1000
12:1000
13:1000
14:1000
15:1000
16:1000
17:1000
18:1000
19:1000
20:1000
21:1000
22:1000
23:1000
24:1000
25:1000
26:1000
27:1000
28:1000
29:1000
30:1000
31:1000
32:1000
33:1000

Comment: looks like you are returning something that was on the stack. you need to malloc the data and return a pointer to it.

Comment: `Graph` not defined.  Post [mcve]